# How to use $in mongo query with ReactiveMongo in Play! Framework 2.6?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo, reactivemongo-play-json

I am trying to use the following find query,

```
{
   "uid" : { "$in" : ["value1", "value2"] }
}
```

The array ["value1", "value2"] should be set dynamically from Scala **Array[String]**.

Here is my code,

```
    def find(uids: Array[String]): Future[Seq[User]] = {
    val query: JsObject = Json.parse(JsonUtil.toInQuery(uids, "uid")).asInstanceOf[JsObject]
    collection.flatMap(_.find(query)
      .cursor[User](ReadPreference.primary)
      .collect[Seq]()
    )
  }
```

The method **JsonUtil.toInQuery(uids, "uid")** is creating the json string of the query. I have tried using BSONDocument and writing Json query manually instead of passing json string, but it does not seem to work.

Can anyone suggest me a working way to use that query in reactive-mongo with play framework 2.6 ?

**Update**

```
public static String toJsonString(String[] arr){
        return Json.toJson(arr).toString();
    }

public static String toInQuery(String[] arr, String item){
    return "{ \""+item+"\": {\"$in\": "+toJsonString(arr)+"}}";
}
```

I got it working. But, not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: The code of `toInQuery` is required (seems unsafe as used with `asInstanceOf`)

Comment: @cchantep  Updated

Comment: That's useless to build the JSON as string and then parse it. Directly build the appropriate JSON value using appropriate class/factory.